# Autodesk Forge Reality Capture: Not reconstructing complete meshes

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

I have lately been working on Forge Reality Capture API and using simple curl commands to reconstruct some scenes from images.
The process goes through smoothly but I never obtain a complete mesh.
1.I have tried increasing the number of images about 5 times ( from 20 to 100)
2.Tried both the obj and rcm formats ( my scenetype=object)
3.I investigated the camera positions after exporting the rcm mesh to Recap photo and only about 15 positions are shown. While I used about 100 frames in several positions. Only the images from these camera positions are stiched and  get an incomplete mesh.

Is this a algorithm issue in the reconstruction?
Do I have to capture more pictures? The area is relatively small, a corridor of 50m*20m. 
Can I re-process the same scene by adding additional photos?
Is there a necessity for some amount of texture?

I am grateful for the answers.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having a look at my blog post on Reality Capture API https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/hitchhikers-guide-reality-capture-api that might help you to debug and identify the source of the problems.

The source of the problem could range from object having transparent or reflective surfaces, to your images (or some of them) not being properly uploaded.

In general, if you don't get complete mesh, the best solution is to take more pictures of the missing spots, instead of more pictures of the entire object. If there are missing spots, it means that the engine could not figure out of your images how to stitch them - more images of those areas should help.

Comment: Thanks for your response Denis.
I did follow the blog and I actually took into account good practice to capture the images.
I understand the limitations.

But as a follow up question:
I tried to recreate the same scene on Recap Photo and the cloud algorithm was able to stitch it perfectly for the same photos. 
In my understanding, both Forge and Recap photo have the same back end algorithm. In this case, why is the Forge pipeline not able to recreate the scene?